# Как синхронизировать доступ к файлу на linux?

Tags: c++, linux, файлы

Пишу программу на C++ для linux, она вызывает уже готовую программу, которую я не могу менять, эта программа создаёт определённый файл. Программа работает в отдельном потоке в интерактивном режиме из терминала и не завершается после генерации файла.

Я ожидаю появления файла в своей программе, пытаясь открыть его. И если предыдущая программа не успела дописать файл, я получаю неполные данные.

Есть ли способ узнать, закрыли ли файл остальные потоки, чтоб можно было корректно прочитать все записанные данные?

Возможно есть событие создания файла, чтоб не ждать его появления в цикле?

Есть ли событие закрытия файла другим потоком?

Пример моей программы, ожидающей файл

```cpp
remove("image.raw");
pid = fork();
switch (pid) {
  case -1:
    return;
  case 0:
    execl("program", "program", NULL);
    return;
}
std::ifstream in;
do {
  usleep(100000);
  in.open("image.raw", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
} while (!in.is_open());
in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data), size);
in.close();
```

[eri](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/16574/eri) предложил использовать inotify, вот пример программы с использованием этой библиотеки

**test_inotify.c**

```c
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define BUF_LEN (sizeof(struct inotify_event) + NAME_MAX + 1)

int main() {
    int f = creat("/tmp/image.raw", S_IRWXU);
    if (f == -1) {
      perror("creat");
    }
    if (close(f) == -1) {
      perror("close");
    }

    int fd = inotify_init1(IN_CLOEXEC);
    if (fd == -1) {
      perror("inotify_init");
      return 1;
    }
    int wd = inotify_add_watch(fd, "/tmp/image.raw", IN_CLOSE_WRITE | IN_ONESHOT);
    if (wd == -1) {
      perror("inotify_add_watch");
      return 1;
    }

    pid_t pid = fork();
    switch (pid) {
      case -1:
        perror("fork");
        return 0;
      case 0:
        if (execl("program", "program", NULL) == -1) {
          perror("execl");
        }
        return 0;
    }

    char buf[BUF_LEN] __attribute__ ((aligned(8)));
    ssize_t num_read = read(fd, buf, BUF_LEN);
    if (num_read == -1) {
      perror("read");
      return 1;
    }
    printf("File image.raw closed\n");

    inotify_rm_watch(fd, wd);
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

**program.c**

```c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int f = open("/tmp/image.raw", O_CREAT | O_RDWR);
  write(f, "test", 4);
  close(f);
  return 0;
}
```

**build.sh**

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

g++ test_inotify.c -o test_inotify
g++ program.c -o program
```

Comment: `in.open("image.raw.works"` ... `in.close();` ... переименовываем на  `"image.raw"` `int rename(const char *oldpath, const char *newpath);`

Comment: одной секунды хватит. Зачем `usleep`? Переименование открытого файла приведёт к ошибке. Что-то не так всё нарисовали.

Comment: Так?
`do {
  usleep(100000);
  rename("image.raw", "image.raw.work");
  in.open("image.raw", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
} while (!in.is_open());
`

Comment: Нет, поставщик файла должен переименовывать. А клиент только циклом открывать.

Comment: Я не могу менять программу, создающую файл.

Comment: Вы всё равно не дойдёте до цикла. `system` - висит до окончания работы другой программы. *Поправьте свой вопрос, что это в другом потоке.*

Comment: Если программа, которую вы запускаете для создания файла, завершается после этого за приемлемое время, то проще всего дождаться ее завершения, а потом спокойно открывать файл

Comment: @avp в случае со сбербанком можно выйграть секунду ;) а ,домыслы конечно,  некоторые программы могуть сидеть резидентно и иногда выплевывать файл

Comment: @eri, в общем случае использование  inotify, как вы предложили, безусловно правильно. Но автор, вообще-то, просто не описал весь сценарий работы. Вот я и пытаюсь подтолкнуть его к улучшению описания ситуации.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, почему переименование открытого файла приведёт к ошибке? (При условии, что и место есть, и файл самый обычный, и пишем куда есть права)

Comment: @0andriy даже место свободное тут не причем. открытый и переименованный файл это одна и та же inode и занимает то же самое место. Разве что перемещение на другой диск - но это не перемещение - это копирование с последующим удалением.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Смена имени, прав и даже удаление не мешает программе дальше записывать файл и не вызывает исключительных ситуаций.

Comment: @eri проверил, вроде-бы ошибок нет. значит перепутал с чем-то.

Comment: @eri под «местом» я имел в виду и наличие свободных inode в том числе.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, исправил в примере запуск программы в отдельном потоке.

Comment: @avp, программа, генерирующая файл не завершается, работает в интерактивном режиме из терминала.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для линукс используй INOTIFY https://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify и жди IN_CLOSE_WRITE

Пример на Си можно встроить в плюсы

```
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#define BUF_LEN (10 * (sizeof(struct inotify_event) + NAME_MAX + 1))

int main(){

    int inotifyFd, wd, done;
    char buf[BUF_LEN] __attribute__ ((aligned(8)));
    ssize_t numRead;
    char *p;
    struct inotify_event *event;
    
    done = 0;
    
    wd = inotify_add_watch(inotifyFd, "/tmp/", IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE|IN_CLOSE_WRITE);

    do {  
        numRead = read(inotifyFd, buf, BUF_LEN);
        for (p = buf; p < buf + numRead; ) {
            event = (struct inotify_event *) p;
            if ( strcmp(event->name, "image.raw") == 0) {
                done = 1;
                printf("File image.raw closed\n");
                break; 
            }
            p += sizeof(struct inotify_event) + event->len;
        };
    } while ( done==0 );
    return 0;
}
```

.. не проверил, может где опечатался.

Comment: Пытаюсь ещё понять предупреждение, что `inotifyFd` должен быть каким-то файл-дескриптором. Каким? "The fd argument is a file descriptor referring to  the       inotify  instance  whose  watch list is to be modified."

Comment: `inotifyFd = inotify_init();`